# prove that BEDF is cyclic

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> In triangle $ABC$, points $D$ and $E$ are chosen on side $CA$ with $AB=AD$ and $BE=EC$ ($E$ lying between $A$ and $D$). Let $F$ be the midpoint of the arc $BC$ of the circumcircle of ABC. Show that $BEDF$ is cyclic.

Note that if $I$ is the incenter of triangle $ABC,$ then $\angle BIC = 90 + \angle A/2$ (since $\angle BIC = 180 - \angle IBC - \angle ICB = 180-(\angle B + \angle C)/2 = 90 + \angle A/2$). Also, since $AD = AB, \angle ADB = 90-\angle A/2$ and $\angle BDC = 90 + \angle A/2$. So $BIDC$ is cyclic. It also seems like $BICF$ is cyclic, but I'm not sure how to prove this.

Comment: could you include a picture that shows what you are talking about?

Comment: We need $AB<AC$ for $E$ to be between $A,D$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really quite easy, no drawing the incenter fancy stuff. It’s sufficient to show that $\angle BDA=\angle BFE$. Because $\triangle BDA$ is isosceles, $\angle BDA=90-\angle A/2$. Obviously $EF$ is the perpendicular bisector of $BC$, so $\angle BFE=\angle BFC/2=(180-\angle A)/2$. Done. Here’s a (bad) diagram (if anyone can make it smaller that would be great):

[image]